# CNN data doesn't fit in memory (kernel dies)

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, out-of-memory

I am working on [this](https://ai4covid-hackathon.it/data/) dataset (the image part), normalized to 1103 images of size 1396 x 1676.
I am trying to feed it to a CNN (taken from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/medical-x-ray-%EF%B8%8F-image-classification-using-convolutional-neural-network-9a6d33b1c2a)) of this shape:

```
n, w, h = X_train.shape # which is (n, 1396, 1676)
cnn = Sequential()
cnn.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(w, h, 1)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(w, h, 1)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(w, h, 1)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(w, h, 1)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
cnn.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu", input_shape=(w, h, 1)))
cnn.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
cnn.add(Flatten())
cnn.add(Dense(activation = 'relu', units = 128))
cnn.add(Dense(activation = 'relu', units = 64))
cnn.add(Dense(activation = 'sigmoid', units = 1))
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

early = EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", mode="min", patience=3)
learning_rate_reduction = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', patience=2, verbose=1,factor=0.3, min_lr=0.000001)
callbacks_list = [early, learning_rate_reduction]

cnn.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=25, validation_split=0.7, callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Both in Google Colab and on a Jupyter in my 16Gb machine, it produces a kernel death. I tried to use a generator to feed just 10 images at a time, but it doesn't produce any good result (0.5 accuracy).

Could you suggest a way to solve this? Maybe tweaking some parameters too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to train on (not considering the data and goal). Your first start is to not use big resolution of the images. Just start small (`256x256 or 512x512`). All you need to do is to resize the images first (use opencv to `resize`) Then train the model on that. It will surely give you (and the hardware) some breathing room.

Comment: Won't that decrease the model precision a lot?

Comment: Technically, yes. But in practice you always start small (specially when you have hardware limitations). I assume you haven't been able to train the model properly, with enough epoc. Some problems are easily solvable by smaller model, and if you keep on making those bigger, you get to a diminishing returns scenario. My suggestion is start small, so that there is no hardware bottleneck.. Then increase size and compare accuracy gains.

Comment: Surprisingly, no.  Most image models are HUGELY overtrained.  You don't really want to use all 2.3 million pixels to identify a trend.  Most of those pixels are irrelevant details.  By reducing the size, you can actually train the model to look for trends instead of wade through details.  Consider looking for a capital E.  You don't really care about sharp edges and the fine details of the serifs.  You just want the generally blobby shape of an E.

Comment: Thank you! Any other suggestions on the NN architecture or training parameters? I'm still getting trash val_accuracy with smaller data

Answer (score 1):

try to reduce the batch size for example use 16 also try to reduce the scale of image